# Auto Refresh Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How can i refresh the Crystal Reports' report data with C# as desktop application. I have create my report but i want to refresh it's data each 2 minutes without clicking any button. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which version of Crystal Reports you're using but I did this in VB.net with Crystal Reports 2008 using a timer control and using the following code;

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

crvActive.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = True ' Do not ask for new parameters

crxReport.Refresh()
crvActive.RefreshReport()

With crvActive ' Get the number of pages after the refresh
    .ShowLastPage()
    NumPages = .GetCurrentPageNumber
    .ShowFirstPage()
End With

Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

crvActive is the Viewer Control on the form, crxReport is the ReportDocument object.  I hope you can translate this into C# and bind it to a Timer event.

Good luck.

Comment: I don't know VB.net and i'm using crystal reports 2005. And also i couldn't see refresh time in your code.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAK For the purpose of this exercise there's very little difference between C# and VB in terms of readability and conversion.  What you need to do is add a timer control to your form and on the fire event do the refresh code I've given you.

Comment: finally i learned the usage of timer function in .NET and repass the values of parameters on each refresh. Because in VS2005 there is one reuseparameter.